# Get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') when pass a params

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

At first, the params does not have any data yet (blank array), but it will update again after `useEffect` set the variable.

But for my highchart, it gave me this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
 52 |   createChart();
 53 | } else {
 54 |   if (props.allowChartUpdate !== false) {
>55 |     if (!props.immutable && chartRef.current) {
    | ^  56 |       chartRef.current.update(
 57 |         props.options,
 58 |         ...(props.updateArgs || [true, true])
```

I searched some solutions, they suggest can use `allowChartUpdate={false}` and `immutable={false}` for solving the problem. After I tried it, yes it does solve my problem, but my highchart doesn't show the data when initial load.

I'm guessing is it the params passing in a blank array at first, then passing a second time with actual values so it causes this problem. If yes, can rerendering the highchart solve the problem? And how can I do that?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-highcharts-error-kkib1?file=/src/App.js) is the link, please help me on it. Thank you muakzzz.

Comment: Have you tried updating using these instructions? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update

Comment: i wish to update it whenever a new data params pass in. How can I do that? Not sure where to write the this.updateSeries.bind(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I managed to get my desired output already. The problem was my parent component will pass a blank array of data into my highchart network graph component at first due to the useEffect used in the parent. And after that, they pass another array with actual data into my highchart network graph component.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Box} from "@mui/material";
import RouteMap from "./Content/RouteMap";
import {getRouteData} from "../../../API/RouteDataAPI"
import Timetable from "./Content/Timetable";
import _ from 'lodash';

function RightContent({contentKey}) {

    const [routeData, setRouteData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getRouteData().then(res => setRouteData(res));
    }, [])

    const mapStation = () => {
        let arr = [], allStation = [], routeMapData = {}

        if (routeData.length !== 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < routeData.length; i++) {
                const station = routeData[i].station;

                for (let j = 0; j < station.length; j++) {
                    const firstStation = station[j];
                    const nextStation = station[j + 1];

                    allStation.push(firstStation.stationName)
                    if (nextStation) {
                        arr.push([firstStation.stationName, nextStation.stationName])
                    }
                }
            }
            routeMapData.data = arr;
            routeMapData.allStation = allStation;
            routeMapData.centralStation = "KL Sentral"
        }

        return routeMapData;
    }

    // const mapStation = () => {
    //     let arr = [];
    //     getRouteData().then(res => {
    //         arr.push(res.flatMap(({station}) => {
    //             return station.reduce((segments, current, i, stations) => {
    //                 if (stations[i + 1]) {
    //                     segments.push(
    //                         current.stationName,
    //                     );
    //                 }
    //                 return segments;
    //             }, []);
    //         }))
    //     })
    //     console.log(arr)
    // }


    const content = (key) => {

        const availableRoute = routeData.map(route => route.routeTitle);

        if (
            key === 'map'
            // && !_.isEmpty(mapStation())
        ){
            // console.log('here', mapRouteData)
            return <RouteMap mapRouteData={mapStation()}/>;
        }
        else if (availableRoute.includes(key)) {
            return <Timetable routeData={routeData} currentRoute={key}/>
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    return (
        <Box className="rightPaper center">
            {content(contentKey)}
        </Box>
    );
}

export default RightContent;
```

^^^This was my parent component.^^^
In the `content` variable function there, I have an if statement with the requirements provided. If you try to uncomment the lodash (second requirement) in the if statement, I can able to get my desire result.

This was my highchart network component.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
import networkgraph from 'highcharts/modules/networkgraph'

require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/export-data')(Highcharts);

if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
    networkgraph(Highcharts);
}

const RouteMap = ({mapRouteData}) => {

    const [seriesData, setSeriesData] = useState(mapRouteData.data);
    const [centralStation, setCentralStation] = useState(mapRouteData.centralStation);
    const [allStation, setAllStation] = useState(mapRouteData.allStation);

    useEffect(() => {
        setSeriesData(mapRouteData.data);
        setCentralStation(mapRouteData.centralStation);
        setAllStation(mapRouteData.allStation);
    }, [mapRouteData])

    Highcharts.addEvent(
        Highcharts.Series,
        'afterSetOptions',
        function (e) {
            let colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
                i = 0,
                nodes = {};

            if (
                this instanceof Highcharts.seriesTypes.networkgraph &&
                e.options.id === 'lang-tree' &&
                e.options.data !== undefined
            ) {
                let lastSecond = '', arry = []
                e.options.data.forEach(function (link) {

                    if (lastSecond !== link[0]) {
                        nodes[link[0]] = {
                            id: link[0],
                            color: colors[++i]
                        }
                    } else if (lastSecond === link[0]) {
                        nodes[link[0]] = {
                            id: link[0],
                            color: colors[i]
                        }
                        nodes[link[1]] = {
                            id: link[1],
                            color: colors[i]
                        }
                        arry.push(link[0])
                    }
                    lastSecond = link[1];

                });

                const exchangeStation = allStation.filter((item, index) => allStation.indexOf(item) !== index);
                i += 1;
                exchangeStation.forEach((station) => {
                    nodes[station] = {
                        id: station,
                        marker: {
                            radius: 18
                        },
                        name: 'Interchange: ' + station,
                        color: colors[i]
                    }
                })

                nodes[centralStation] = {
                    id: centralStation,
                    name: 'Sentral Station: ' + centralStation,
                    marker: {
                        radius: 25
                    },
                    color: colors[++i]
                }


                e.options.nodes = Object.keys(nodes).map(function (id) {
                    return nodes[id];
                });

            }
        }
    );

    const options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'networkgraph',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'The Route Map'
        },
        caption: {
            text: "Click the button at top right for more options."
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            networkgraph: {
                keys: ['from', 'to'],
                layoutAlgorithm: {
                    enableSimulation: true,
                    // linkLength: 7
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                link: {
                    width: 4,
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 10
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    linkFormat: "",
                    allowOverlap: false
                },
                id: "lang-tree",
                data: seriesData
            }
        ]
    };

    return <HighchartsReact
        ref={useRef()}
        containerProps={{style: {height: "100%", width: "100%"}}}
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
    />;
}

export default RouteMap;
```

Sorry for the lengthy code here. By the way, feel free to let me know any improvements I can make in my code. First touch on react js project and still have a long journey to go.

Once again~ Thank you!

Comment: @SebastianHajdus If for my code here, how can I apply the update chart after render?

Comment: `https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9nmmcz?file=index.js` Here is an example of how to update a chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead just provide the `getRouteData` function as an initializer function directly to the `useState` hook to provide the initial state. So long as it's not asynchronous it will provide initial state for the initial render, no need to use the `useEffect` hook to populate state *after* the first render.

Additionally, you should initialize `routeMapData` to have the `data` property array by default so you don't accidentally pass it through with an undefined `data` property, which was part of the problem you were seeing.

```
export default function App() {
  const [routeData] = useState(getRouteData()); // <-- initialize state

  const mapStation = () => {
    const routeMapData = {
      data: [], // <-- data array to push into
    };

    if (routeData.length !== 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < routeData.length; i++) {
        const station = routeData[i].station;

        for (let j = 0; j < station.length; j++) {
          const firstStation = station[j];
          const nextStation = station[j + 1];

          if (nextStation) {
            routeMapData.data.push([ // <-- push into array
              firstStation.stationName,
              nextStation.stationName
            ]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return routeMapData;
  };

  const content = (key) => {
    if (key === "map") {
      return <RouteMap mapRouteData={mapStation()} />;
    }

    return null;
  };

  return <Box className="rightPaper center">{content("map")}</Box>;
}
```

You don't need to even use the local state as you can directly consume the returned array from `getRouteData` in the `mapStation` utility function.

```
export default function App() {
  const mapStation = () => {
    return {
      data: getRouteData().flatMap(({ station }) => {
        return station.reduce((segments, current, i, stations) => {
          if (stations[i + 1]) {
            segments.push([
              current.stationName,
              stations[i + 1].stationName
            ]);
          }
          return segments;
        }, []);
      })
    };
  };

  const content = (key) => {
    if (key === "map") {
      return <RouteMap mapRouteData={mapStation()} />;
    }

    return null;
  };

  return <Box className="rightPaper center">{content("map")}</Box>;
}
```

[image: Edit get-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-foreach-when-pass]

Comment: Ohh i see, but actually the getRouteData() was actually calling from API and it give me Promises, which make me heart pain . I search online and said can remove it by using .then(). So in this case what do you suggest to edit?

Comment: @KingsleyYong Ah, well in that case the above won't completely work, but you can use some "loading" state to hold off on rendering the `RouteMap` component until the station map data has been fetched and saved into state. If you update your question to be a little more representative of your *actual* use case I can continue helping.

Comment: do you mind talking in discord? Kingwashere#4632, I not sure how to present my case here.

Comment: @KingsleyYong Oh, sorry, I meant if you could just update the question to include a code example that is closer to what you are trying to do, namely the asynchronous fetch. I can update my answer to include a general solution to what I'm referring to with a "loading" state if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed adding ***True*** for **allowChartUpdate** and **immutable**

```
  <HighchartsReact
            ref={chartRef}
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={options}
            containerProps={containerProps}
            allowChartUpdate={true}
            immutable={true}
        />
```